# ggplot2: smooth and fill

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'd like to smooth the geom_lines and fill the area between. I've tried stat_smooth() to smooth the lines, and both geom_ribbon() and geom_polygon() but without success.

Apologies for the double barrel question.

[image: Smooth and fill]

```
bell <- data.frame(
                month = c("Launch","1st","2nd","3rd","4th","5th","6th","7th","8th","9th","10th","11th","12th"),
                rate  = c(0,.05,.12,.18,.34,.42,.57,.68,.75,.81,.83,.85,.87))
bell$month <- factor(bell$month, levels = rev(c("Launch","1st","2nd","3rd","4th","5th","6th","7th","8th","9th","10th","11th","12th")))

ggplot() +
        theme_minimal() +
        coord_flip() +
        scale_fill_manual(values=cols) +
        geom_line(data=bell, aes(x=month, y=.5-(rate/2), group=1), color='pink', size=1) +
        geom_line(data=bell, aes(x=month, y=.5+(rate/2), group=1), color='pink', size=1) +
        theme(legend.position='none', axis.ticks=element_blank(), axis.text.x=element_blank(),axis.title.x=element_blank())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to calculate the points of the `loess` regression outside of ggplot and then plot them using `geom_line` (for a line) or `geom_area` for a filled area (`geom_area` is `geom_ribbon`, but with ymin fixed at zero).

Also, you don't need `coord_flip`. Instead, just switch your `x` and `y` mappings. This is necessary anyway if you want to fill underneath the curve.

In the example below I've created a numeric month variable for the regression. I've also commented out the `scale_fill_manual` line because your example doesn't provide a `cols` vector and the plot code doesn't produce a legend anyway. I've also commented out the `legend.position='none'` line as it's superfluous.

```
bell$month.num = 0:12

m1 = loess(rate ~ month.num, data=bell)
bell$loess.mod = predict(m1)

ggplot(bell, aes(y=month, group=1)) +
  theme_minimal() +
  #scale_fill_manual(values=cols) +
  geom_area(aes(x=.5-(loess.mod/2)), fill='pink', size=1) +
  geom_area(aes(x=.5+(loess.mod/2)), fill='pink', size=1) +
  theme(#legend.position='none', 
        axis.ticks=element_blank(), 
        axis.text.x=element_blank(),
        axis.title.x=element_blank())
```

[image]